# cross-compilation right way

Tags: compilation, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I have an arm based board. I would like to cross-compile software for it using my x86 based pc.

What I have done(on my x86 pc):

- Install arm compiler for x86.
- Copy on my pc a set of file (arm library and headers)
- Create a CMakeLists.txt file that indicates where to find    arm
  library

Drawback of my approach:

- If I need a new library, then I have to install it on arm pc and re-copy the arm enviroment on x86 pc.

Question, is it the right way to cross-compile?

Comment: Why do you need a new library everytime you are compiling? I am a bit confused here, can you please tell what kind of new library you are using or how is it that you need a new library every now and then!

Comment: I wouldn't say that I need a new library for every compilation.
Suppose I introduce a new feature in my code that uses library dummylib. 
I have to install dummylib on my target pc and copy his enviroment on the host pc.

Comment: `Every time I need a new library I have to install on arm pc that library and re-copy the arm enviroment on my pc.` You mentioned in your question.

Comment: `I have to install dummylib on my target pc and copy his enviroment on the host pc.` Well, you don't have to install that dummylib on your host PC, you just have to copy the cross-compiled library on the host PC if you already got a pre-compiled library otherwise you have to cross-compile the dummylib on your host PC and then if it is a shared library (which I am assuming from your question) then you have to copy that cross-compiled `.so` file on the target board (ARM board) and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So that the executable can find the shared library during runtime.

Comment: Question modified. Thanks. 
Well the problem is that tipically I dont have a pre-compiled library.
Compiling it on my host pc require that any library that it uses must be present on my system. 
By the way, in some cases it can be an improvement...thanks!

Comment: During the development phase, you have to do it over and over. But when you are releasing a version you have to release an Image file, which will contain the executable and the dummylib.

Comment: using ExternalProject_Add you can add it to your Project CMakeLists which built it on time when need it...